# extract string between '$$' characters - $$extractabc$$

Tags: shell

I am working on shell script and new to it. I want to extract the string between double `$$` characters, for example:

input:

```
$$extractabc$$
```

output

```
extractabc
```

I used grep and sed but not working out. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Your question has received some good answers. Please put a closure to your question by marking an answer of your choice as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
awk -F"$" '{print $3}' file.txt
```

assuming the file contained `input:$$extractabc$$ output:extractabc`. `awk` splits your data into pieces using `$` as a delimiter. First item will be `input:`, next will be empty, next will be `extractabc`.

You could use sed like so to get the same info.

```
sed -e 's/.*$$\(.*\)$$.*/\1/' file.txt
```

`sed` looks for information between $$s and outputs that. The goal is to type something like this `.*$$(.*)$$.*`. It's greedy but just stay with me.

- looks for `.*` - i.e. any character zero or more times before $$
- then the string should have $$
- after $$ there'll be any character zero or more times
- then the string should have another $$
- and some more characters to follow
- between the 2 $$ is `(.*)`. String found between $$s is given a placeholder `\1`
- sed finds such information and publishes it

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working fine on command line but when I use inside the script, it's not working out.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question that you are using it in a script. Edit your question and update it with the script you have, the error you are seeing etc.

Comment: You awk does not work,  does not give any output.  PS line is `$$extractabc$$$` not `input:$$extractabc$$ output:extractabc`

Comment: @Jotne Why wouldn't it work? For both inputs, actually.

Comment: @Jotne I just tried putting `$$extractabc$$$` in file.txt and used `awk -F"$" '{print $3}' file.txt`. That gave me the correct information `extractabc`. If you have a sample file, go ahead and provide a link. Also include the output of `awk --version`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` PCRE (where available) and look-around:

```
$ echo '$$extractabc$$' | grep -oP "(?<=\\$\\$).*(?=\\$\\$)"
extractabc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '$$extractabc$$' | awk '{gsub(/\$\$/,"")}1'
extractabc
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add some explanation so users can make use of your answer more readily. code only answer sometimes wont serve the purpose for users and its difficult to understand -Review

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other variation:

```
echo "$$extractabc$$" | awk -F"$$" 'NF==3 {print $2}'
```

It does test of there are two set of `$$` and only then prints whats between `$$`

Does also work for input like `blabla$$some_data$$moreblabla`

Answer (score 0):

How about remove all the $ in the input?

```
$ echo '$$extractabc$$' | sed 's/\$//g'
extractabc
```

Same with `tr`

```
$ echo '$$extractabc$$' | tr -d '$'
extractabc
```